# Broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE not work in Android 11

Tags: android, adb

I need to push a folder which contains a video into Android `/sdcard` and will use it as a new photo gallery.

It works well in Android 10, but I couldn't get this photo gallery in Google Pixel 4(Android 11)

```sh
 $ tree newcase
newcase
└── jet_half.mp4

$ adb push newcase /sdcard
newcase/: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 31.7 MB/s (365194876 bytes in 10.983s)

$ adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file:///sdcard/newcase/jet_half.mp4
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///sdcard/newcase/jet_half.mp4 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Comment: Try /sdcard/Documents/newcase/... Further it is unclear if you cannot copy the folder or that you cannot let it scan.

Comment: @blackapps Indeed, please reply it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: What am I doing wrong in Android 10, then? I'm using this exact command (only the path changed as appropriate) but neither the stock Files app nor Google Photos notices the new image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 11 will not let you touching root of external storage.

Try

```
/sdcard/Documents/newcase/...
```